# dynamically add link buttons in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem that I am creating linkbuttons dynamically in a panel in asp.net but I can not place it new lines, it only appears together. Please help me out.

My Code is:

```
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        lb.ID = TextBox2.Text;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lb);

        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("
        "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to surround the LinkButton in a block-level HTML element such as `<div>` or `<p>`, or insert a `LiteralControl` with a line break tag `<br/>` *before* you add the LinkButton

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.Text = TextBox1.Text;
lb.ID = TextBox2.Text;
Panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
```

Or...

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div>"));
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.Text = TextBox1.Text;
lb.ID = TextBox2.Text;
Panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
```